# Ajax response is OK but not displaying

Tags: php, ajax

In one of my web application I have a "Mark as Favorite icon". So when some one clicks on this button. It disappears and an ajax request is called

```
jQuery('.favr').click(function() {

                    var user_IDs = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                    var current_IDs = '<?php echo $cui ?>'; 

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {'ajaxreturn': '102', 'logedid': current_IDs,'ids':user_IDs},
                        success: function(result) {
                            jQuery('.favh').html(result);
                        }

                    });
                });
```

which inserts the user id in database and returns a response with an icon "Remove Favorite". All this is working OK. Ajax response is

```
<i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>
```

I can see this response in my google chrome Network tab. But the problem is this response doesn't display in the the div element with class .favh and remains empty.
Please tell me where I am wrong.
I am working in wordpress that's why I used

```
url: '<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/',
```

Here is my php code, that ajax calls

```
 add_action('init','my_ajaxreturn_102');

    function my_ajaxreturn_102(){

    if ($_POST['ajaxreturn'] == 102) {
    $userID = $_POST['ids'];
    $loggedID = $_POST['logedid'];

    $rem_array = json_decode(get_user_meta($loggedID, 'meta_favorite', true), true);
    $fav_array = array_unique($rem_array);
    $searched_item = array_search($userID,$fav_array);
    unset($fav_array[$searched_item]);


    update_user_meta( $loggedID, 'meta_favorite', json_encode($fav_array));
    echo '<i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>';
    exit;
}
    }
```

All this code is working fine, sending response

```
<i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>
```

but only problem is not displaying this response.

Comment: What comes back in "results" if you alert(result) in your success function?

Comment: this is the ajax response which I can see in google chrome Network tab.  <i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>  but the div element where I want to display it remains empty. Nothing displays there and when I check by inspect element, it is empty. thanks for replay

Comment: First, `'<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/'` is wrong. It should be `'<?php bloginfo("url") ?>/'`

Comment: @Riz try alert the result and see what it shows

Comment: but it is working well. I have used it in my other applications also and I am receiving response. the problem for me is that response is not displaying at  my desired location. thanks

Comment: @Riz if you want help, follow the steps asked of you... Alert it, trust us. Your class isn't closed properly, nor do you have any quotation marks around your ID. Whatever PHP you have putting $userID in is wrong.

Comment: @Riz First check the response with alert

Comment: another thing when I replace the response <i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>    by some character like bbbb then these character displays accurately.

Comment: Yes, it is alerting the correct response <i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>

Comment: @Riz can you post the PHP code that your AJAX calls please? Update your original question with it.

Comment: @Riz which browser you are using? is the class `.favh` is correct?

Comment: Can you manually add some html to .favh on a button click to verify that you have the correct class?

Comment: `echo '<i data-tooltip="" data-selector="tooltip0D27OP" title="Remove Favorite" class="has-tip tip-left radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-'. $userID .' id='. $userID.' ></i>';` is wrong. Use single and double quotes properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `"` to close your class tag in your response.

Comment: OK, I have updated my question and added php code also but let me check Rofez answer. May be this is a problem

Comment: OH, thanks Rofez. that was a problem. now it working fine. Thank you very much

Comment: Problem is resolved but now tooltip doesn't changes its text. e.g after changing the icon of "Mark as Favorit" to "Remove Favorite", tooltip should show the message "Remove Favorite" but it is still showing "Mark as Favorite". Can anybody help me? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I was in exam... You should try to empty your class before rewriting in it, just write `$('.favh').empty();` just before this line: `jQuery('.favh').html(result);` in your ajax. Note that you can use '$' instead of 'jQuery', it's the same thing but shorter to write =).